# Django REST API POST to Python script

Tags: django

Is it possible to run a Python script with the POST data as soon as a POST request is triggered or a new entry added to the Django REST API ?

I'm very new to Django, please explain in detail for answer.

Comment: What kind of python script?

Comment: @OceanFire It is a python script which deals with opencv and pytesseract. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Your question is not accurate. It's hard to understand what it is about. Django is python based so you can run any script you like.